# How can I bold text in telepot Telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telepot

I have tried this

```
elif command == 'bold':
    telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("*bold*"), reply_markup=markup)
```

But it is replying `*bold*` instead of **bold**

Comment: According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/telegram/status/817080202257952768), the format is now `**bold**`

Comment: @gogaz Still not working. Replying `**bold**` now.

Comment: what exact `markup` do you use?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov `reply_markup=markup`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to provide a `parse_mode` Parameter (parse_mode="Markdown").

Or else you will not see any markdown style.

```
sendMessage(chat_id, "*this text is bold*", parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

See

https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#telepot.Bot.sendMessage

Comment: I'm getting this error: `NameError: name markdown is not defined`

Comment: elif command == 'bold': telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str,parse_mode="Markdown"("*bold*"), reply_markup=markup)

Comment: `telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "*this text is bold*", parse_mode= 'Markdown')`

Answer (score 4):

I had that same issue with Markdown parse_mode. I've written send_message on my own, without using telepot's sendMessage method. In this case, its much easier to understand how to deal with this problem:

```
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>'

def send_message(chat_id, text='empty line', parse_mode = 'Markdown'):
    URL = url + 'sendMessage'
    answer = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'parse_mode': 'Markdown'}
    r = requests.post(URL, json=answer)
    return r.json()

if (text == '/bold'):
    send_message(chat_id, 'Here comes the'+'*'+'bold'+'*'+'text!')
```

On the other hand, you could use curl for sending bold text:

```
if (text == '/bold'):
    URL = url + 'sendMessage?chat_id='+chat_id+'&text=*Here comes the bold text*&parse_mode=Markdown'
    answer = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}
    r = requests.post(URL, json=answer)
```

Answer (score 3):

abstracted from --> [How can I write bold in python telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327296/how-can-i-write-bold-in-python-telegram-bot)

You should use:

```
  bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="*bold* Example message", 
            parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

Or:

```
  bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='<b>Example message</b>', 
              parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
```

More info at: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#message-formatting-bold-italic-code-

Comment: This question is for telepot api. Not python-telegram-bot.