# How to send Telegram Bold message using the Native API?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to send a **Telegram** message using the native Python requests so that the "First Name" is received in using in **BOLD**. I have tried HTML and Markdown syntax but it's not showing.

```
import json
import requests

# Telegram bot configurations
TELE_TOKEN='TOKEN'
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TELE_TOKEN)

def send_message(text, chat_id):
    url = URL + "sendMessage?text={}&chat_id={}".format(text, chat_id)
    requests.get(url)

# AWS Lambda handler    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    message = json.loads(event['body'])
    chat_id = message['message']['chat']['id']
    first_name = message['message']['chat']['first_name']
    text = message['message']['text']

    # How can the first name be in BOLD?
    reply = "Hello " + first_name + "! You have said:" + text
    
    send_message(reply, chat_id)
    

    return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/api/entities tried this styled text.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49327656/9474700

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telegram supports formatting in either HTML or Markdown. For formatting, you have to set the `parse_mode` parameter to either `HTML`,`Markdown` (legacy), or`MarkdownV2`.

E.g.: To get the output as "**bold text**", you could use,
`text=<b>bold text</b>&parse_mode=HTML`  or
`text=*bold text*&parse_mode=Markdown`  or
`text=*bold text*&parse_mode=MarkdownV2`.

You could simply do that change in your code snippet;

```
def send_message(text, chat_id):
    url = URL + "sendMessage?text={}&chat_id={}&parse_mode=MarkdownV2".format(text, chat_id)
    requests.get(url)

# AWS Lambda handler    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    # How can the first name be in BOLD?
    reply = "Hello *" + first_name + "*! You have said:" + text
    ...
```

Read more about the formatting options here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options